# Default preference of executable over built-ins with the same name

Tags: bash, shell, path, shell-builtin

I was playing around a bit with the names of some executables, putting them in a folder, `~/bin`, which is in my `$PATH`. Now I'm wondering how I can set the preferences of a `bash-3.2` terminal so that it picks up these executables instead of the builtins or aliases to execute.

For example, if I put a script named `cd` in a directory in `$PATH`, the builtin for `cd` is still executed. However, if I create an `alias` for `cd`, then this alias will be executed, overriding the builtin.

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

#### My questions

1. Is there a way to make an executable file in `$PATH` have, by default, preference over a shell builtin, by executing only, e.g. `cd` without having to resort to using the commands `builtin` or `command`?
2. I'm also interested in any official reference which discusses this preference (not the reasoning, that I do understand).

**Note:** This question is purely for personal educational purposes, I am wondering why it works the way it works.

Comment: To the close voters: Note that this is in my opinion NOT a duplicate, because I am specifically not looking for `command` answers.

Comment: @slm Well, there is only three close votes, and you can always retract it afaik. But I also updated the title.

Comment: I'm saving the vote for after it gets closed to reopen, that's generally how it goes (it's @ 4 now).

Comment: Seems like a better title would've been "How do I override Bash from using builtins, and always search the $PATH?". That sep. you from the other Q, then inside the body you can expand what you're asking.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I attempted to edit it. Feel free to revert but I think you actually have a good Q, it just needed to be polished a bit. Any thoughts on changing the title? I'll start the reopen now.

Comment: Aren't you just looking for aliases? I mean `alias cd=/bin/cd` will override the `cd` builtin.

Comment: @terdon I think that might answer the question as it is stated, but it is not really what I am looking for from an educational perspective. The `enable` in the answer is more the answer that I intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is, is there a way to make an executable file in `$PATH`
>   have preference over an shell builtin, by executing only, e.g. `cd`
>   without builtin or command?

You can use the builtin `enable` to disable/enable a builtin.  Say:

```
enable -n cd
```

to disable the builtin `cd`.  Say `enable cd` to enable the builtin.

The following would give an example of switching between the builtin and command:

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ enable -n cd
$ type cd
-bash: type: cd: not found
$ enable cd
$ type kill
kill is a shell builtin
$ enable -n kill
$ type kill
kill is /bin/kill
$ enable kill
$ type kill
kill is a shell builtin
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Disable "commands" one at a time

You can use the commands `command` and `builtin` to call out one or the other.

```
$ command cd
```

Will disregard any builtins by that name and search the `$PATH`. The opposite command to this which will only use a builtin is `builtin`.

```
$ builtin cd
```

#### Disable builtins

```
$ help enable
enable: enable [-a] [-dnps] [-f filename] [name ...]
    Enable and disable shell builtins.

    Enables and disables builtin shell commands.  Disabling allows you to
    execute a disk command which has the same name as a shell builtin
    without using a full pathname.

    Options:
      -a    print a list of builtins showing whether or not each is enabled
      -n    disable each NAME or display a list of disabled builtins
      -p    print the list of builtins in a reusable format
      -s    print only the names of Posix `special' builtins

    Options controlling dynamic loading:
      -f    Load builtin NAME from shared object FILENAME
      -d    Remove a builtin loaded with -f

    Without options, each NAME is enabled.

    To use the `test' found in $PATH instead of the shell builtin
    version, type `enable -n test'.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless NAME is not a shell builtin or an error occurs.
```

#### Example

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ enable -n cd
$ type cd
cd is /usr/bin/cd

$ enable cd
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

Comment: In my opinion this is not an answer to my question, because I want to specifically know whether I can change or not, somehow, the default behavior of `cd`, without `command` or `builtin`

Comment: In its current form it answer what you wrote. Perhaps you should refine your Q then?

Comment: No, because `command cd` would only "Runs COMMAND with ARGS ignoring shell functions.Runs COMMAND with ARGS ignoring shell functions.", so `command cd` will still call the builtin cd. Anyhow, I did update the question.

Comment: Note that I am using `bash`. For `zsh` `command` seems to do that indeed.